# beautifulsoup table tree: find all tr between two objects?

Tags: python, html, tree, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hi say I have HTML table like this (self-explained by the comment in the code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<tbody>
    <!-- there is a box -->
    <tr>RED BOX</tr>

        <!-- containing the following balls, each <td> has a ball -->
        <!-- may be more than one <tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td>ball 1</td>
            <td>ball 2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>ball 3</td>
        </tr>

    <!-- another box -->
    <tr>GREEN BOX</tr>

        <!-- containing the following balls -->
        <tr>
            <td>ball 4</td>
        </tr>

</tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

As indicated by the comment in the code: RED BOX is a `tr`, and ball 1, 2, 3 are in RED BOX, which is shown by the structure that ball 1, 2, 3 are in `tr` after `<tr>RED BOX</tr>` (balls may be in one or more `tr`). GREEN BOX is another `tr`, and ball 4 is in `tr` after that.

I want to find the balls in each box. I can locate `<tr>RED BOX</tr>` and `<tr>GREEN BOX</tr>` by

```
tr_box = bs.findAll(text=[regex 'something BOX'])
```

and I can find the next `tr` using

```
for t in tr_box:
    t[0].find_next('tr')
```

(which can find ball 1, 2, and 4, and misses ball 3)

But (1) is there something like `find_between_objects` which can find all `tr` between `<tr>RED BOX</tr>` and `<tr>GREEN BOX</tr>`? or some function that cuts all `tr` into sections, divided by `<tr>RED BOX</tr>` and `<tr>GREEN BOX</tr>`?

(2) how to find all `tr` between `<tr>GREEN BOX</tr>` and the end of table `</tbody>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and `break` when you meet a row with a `GREEN BOX`.

```
red_box = soup.find("tr", text="RED BOX")
for row in red_box.find_next_siblings("tr"):
    if row.get_text(strip=True) == "GREEN BOX":
        break

    print([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")])
```

Or [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) if you want to go more Pythonic with that.

**Option 2:** [a search function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

```
def filter_rows(tag):
    return tag.name == "tr" and \
           tag.find_previous_sibling("tr", text="RED BOX") and \
           tag.find_next_sibling("tr", text="GREEN BOX")

for row in soup.find_all(filter_rows):
    print([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")])
```

Both options would print:

```
['ball 1', 'ball 2']
['ball 3']
```

---

> (2) how to find all tr between GREEN BOX and the end of table ?

This would just be:

```
green_box = soup.find("tr", text="GREEN BOX")
for row in green_box.find_next_siblings("tr"):
    print([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")])
```

No need to break the loop here, `find_next_siblings()` would naturally stop when no further matching siblings left.

---

FYI, [complete gist](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/574b2d42f61b737385b3) here.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the "balls" from the "boxes", it may be simpler to use this approach.  Find all the `tr`s then find all the `td`s inside those `tr`s:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        print(td.text)
```

prints:

```
ball 1
ball 2
ball 3
ball 4
```